# How do I force an incompatible pod install?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Really need to upgrade my FBSDK but it's stuck. I don't think there would be problems if it was allowed to go through somehow.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBSDKCoreKit":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    FBSDKCoreKit (= 4.40.0, ~> 4.28)

  In Podfile:
    ExpoKit/Core (from `http://github.com/expo/expo.git`, tag `ios/2.8.3`) was resolved to 2.8.3, which depends on
      FBSDKCoreKit (~> 4.28)

    FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.6.0)

Specs satisfying the `FBSDKCoreKit (~> 5.6.0), FBSDKCoreKit (= 4.40.0, ~> 4.28), FBSDKCoreKit (~> 4.28)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Comment: Try to update `ExpoKit/Core` for a version supporting the 5.6.0 version.

Comment: @Larme I would love to but the last 3 times I tried I was unsuccessful after about half a day. I'll have to do at one point yes, but for now would just like a way to force install the FBSDK.

Comment: You can’t really. Your code won’t compile beacause of breaking change I strongly suspect that.